# NSObjectController in object mode in Swift

Tags: swift, nsobjectcontroller

How do I configure an `NSObjectController` in object mode in Swift?

Let's say I have a class A:

```
class A {}
```

Here's what I have tried:

```
let oc = NSObjectController()
oc.objectClass = A.self
oc.newObject() // error
```

The last line produces an error:

```
Unrecognized selector -[Test.A init]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class needs to inherit from NSObject.

This works for me:

```
class A: NSObject {}

let oc = NSObjectController()
oc.objectClass = A.self
let o = oc.newObject()
```